# SQL script performs poorly and to improve performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out if anyone can explain the poor performance of the following query on a large data set, and how you would improve the performance.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Contract_Position Cpos 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Contract_Agreement Cagg ON Cpos.Contract_ID = Cagg.Contract_ID 
OR (Cpos.Contract_ID IS NULL AND Cagg.Contract_ID IS NULL)
```

Comment: Please provide the table structures, and ideally the execution plan

Comment: What happens when you omit the last line of your query (the `OR` statement)?

Comment: your `or (Cpos.Contract_id is null and Cagg.Contract_id is null)` is going to lead to a Cartesian/cross join where the amount of rows where `Cpos.Contract_ID is null` is multiplied by the amount of rows where `Cagg.Contract_ID IS null`. If you have a large dataset and a reasonable amount of rows, I would imagine that would be quite a bit to return.

Comment: If you can replace the `*` from the specific columns you need, and try to filter like last year or something else, would be great, and what is the goal of `OR (Cpos.Contract_ID IS NULL AND Cagg.Contract_ID IS NULL)` for the analysis

Comment: The OR statement is definitely the issue.  That will return all rows from Contract_Position with a NULL contract id with all rows from the Contract Agreement table that have a null contract id.  This could get very large.  If there are 100 rows in each, that's 100 * 100.  Is this what you want?

Comment: if you are treating NULL as a value, can you replace the NULL values in each table with some sort of default value like a 0 or -1?  Then you could take out the OR.

Comment: Selecting every from Contract_Position_Cpos might be a problem if there are a lot of records.